# Suitecrm create user using api

Tags: suitecrm

My question is when i create new user in SUITECRM, i want to insert data in another application and other CodeIgniter database.

Please help me, about how to solve above problem.

I have create custom insert insert api  like:

```
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// get database connection
include_once '../config/database.php';

// instantiate product object
include_once '../objects/product.php';

$database = new Database();

$db = $database->getConnection();

$product = new Product($db); 
//get posted data
$data = (object) $_POST;

//$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// set product property values
$product->name = $data->name;
$product->description = $data->description;
$product->price = $data->price;
$product->category_id = $data->category_id;
$product->created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// create the product
if($product->create()){
    echo '{';
        echo '"message": "Product was created."';
    echo '}';
}

// if unable to create the product, tell the user
else{
    echo '{';
        echo '"message": "Unable to create product."';
    echo '}';
}
?>
```

Comment: using logic hook?

Comment: Can u give me some example or like about it

Comment: https://docs.suitecrm.com/developer/logic-hooks/